# Joining two datasets in R

Tags: r, dataset

I got 2 Dataset that I want to combine

```
Dataset_1:

id| value_1
1 |   a
1 |   b
1 |   b
2 |   a
2 |   a
2 |   b
...

Dataset_2:

id| value_2
1 |   123
1 |   433
1 |   234
2 |   222
2 |   333
2 |   333
...
```

and the result should look like:

```
id| value_1 | value 2
1 |   a     | 123
1 |   b     | 433
1 |   b     | 234
2 |   a     | 222
2 |   a     | 333
2 |   b     | 333
```

if tried to use these functions:

```
inner_join(dataset_1,dataset_2,by="id")
and
full_join(dataset_1,dataset_2,by="id") 
and
merge(dataset_1,dataset_2,by="id")
```

but i always get all possible combinations of the 2 datasets and not the combined one.
It should be simple but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

id is a double, value_1 is a chr and value_2 is an int.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In your situation, try `cbind`.If you want to use joins you have to have a rule which row of `Dataset_1` is to be joined with which row in `Dataset_2`. For example, why is it that in the second row of your expected output `value 2` is equal to  `433` and not `234`.

Comment: I believe the join functions are defaulting to "natural joins" because there are duplicated id values in the id cols? Try '?inner_join' to see the help file.

Comment: Eventually you can use `cbind(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example displays the need for a bind not a join.

```
Dataset_3 <- bind_cols(Dataset_1,Dataset_2[-1]  )
```

What happening is:

> When a join finds a repeated id, it creates more cases for each combination of results.